# How to make a GitHub Actions workflow dry

Tags: terraform, github-actions

Is it possible for a workflow to depend on another workflow?

I currently have 2 workflows for my test  branch.The first is github_action_pull_test.yml that is triggered by a pull_request.When there is a pull_request on the test branch the workflow run to terragrunt plan.The second is github_action_push_test.yml that is triggered when there is a merge to my test branch,the workflow run terragrunt apply.

The current setup has one negative effect:
my github_action_push_test.yml include all the steps in the github_action_pull_test.yml.
Is there a way I can have one workflow that include all the steps but only run terragrunt apply after terragrunt plan has been reviewed and merged into the test branch so i can avoid duplications

```
github_action_pull_test.yml

name: 'GitHub OIDC workflow'
on:
  pull_request:
       branches:
         - test
env:
  tf_version: 'latest'
  tg_version: 'latest'
  tf_working_dir: './testing'
permissions:
    id-token: write
    contents: read
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: 'Build and Deploy'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: 'checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@master
        with:
          aws-region: us-east-1
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/GitHubActions_Workflow_role
          role-duration-seconds: 3600

      - name: 'Terragrunt Init'
        uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
          tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'init'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
          tf_actions_comment: true
        env:
          TF_INPUT: false


      - name: 'Terragrunt Validate'
        uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
          tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
          tf_actions_binary: 'terraform'
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'validate'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
          tf_actions_comment: true

      - name: 'Terragrunt Plan'
        uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
          tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'plan'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
          tf_actions_comment: true

github_action_push_test.yml

name: 'GitHub OIDC workflow'
on:
  push:
       branches:
         - test
env:
  tf_version: 'latest'
  tg_version: 'latest'
  tf_working_dir: './testing'
permissions:
    id-token: write
    contents: read
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: 'Build and Deploy'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: 'checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@master
        with:
          aws-region: us-east-1
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/GitHubActions_Workflow_role
          role-duration-seconds: 3600

      - name: 'Terragrunt Init'
        uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
          tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'init'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
          tf_actions_comment: true
        env:
          TF_INPUT: false


      - name: 'Terragrunt Validate'
        uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
          tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
          tf_actions_binary: 'terraform'
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'validate'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
          tf_actions_comment: true

      - name: 'Terragrunt Plan'
        uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
          tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'plan'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
          tf_actions_comment: true

      - name: 'Terragrunt Apply'
        uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
          tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'apply'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
          tf_actions_comment: true
```

Comment: Have you looked into reusable workflows? https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-24-github-actions-reusable-workflows-are-generally-available/

Comment: You could also combine the two workflows into one and add an `if: github.ref == 'refs/head/test'` to the `apply` step. This combined workflow would be triggered on `push` to any branch. Unless of course there's a specific reason you're using `on: pull_request`, but then you could still use both triggers and distinguish the two with an `if github.event...`

Comment: thank you so much for your answer..it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `first` trigger `second`:

```yaml
name: second

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [first]
    types: [completed]
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build-second:
    name: Second
    if: github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

The `if` expression at the job-level means that `build-second` will only run if the `first` workflow has been successful.